How can I use DihedralAngle to get correct result?
Let $S.ABCD$ be a pyramid, $ABCD$ is a square with $AB = 1$. The line $SA$ perpendicular to the plane $ABC$.

Calculate dihedral angle of two halfplanes SBC and SCD if: $SA = 1$, $SA = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.
In two this codes, I use VectorAngle and DihedralAngle to calculate.  The results of VectorAngle are correct. With DihedralAngle, I don't know how to choose the Out.
Clear["Global`*"];
pB = {1, 0, 0};
pC = {1, 1, 0};
pS = {0, 0, 1};
pD = {0, 1, 0};
n1 = Cross[pS - pB, pS - pC];
n2 = Cross[pS - pD, pS - pC];
VectorAngle[n1, n2]
DihedralAngle[{pS, pC}, {pS - pB, pS - pD}]
DihedralAngle[{pC, pS}, {pB - pS, pD - pS}]


Clear["Global`*"];
a = 1;
h = Sqrt[2]/2;
pB = {a, 0, 0};
pC = {a, a, 0};
pS = {0, 0, h};
pD = {0, a, 0};
n1 = Cross[pB - pC, pB - pD];
n2 = Cross[pB - pS, pB - pD];
VectorAngle[n1, n2]
DihedralAngle[{pB, pD}, {pB - pC, pB - pS}]
DihedralAngle[{pD, pB}, {pC - pB, pS - pB}]


How can I use DihedralAngle to get correct result?

What is the coorect result?

Which answer is wrong?

@cvgmt 2Pi/3 and 3*Pi/4

Should be DihedralAngle[{pS, pC}, {pB - pS, pD - pC}]

@A.Kato 4Pi/3 and 5*Pi/4.

@cvgmt what is the rule?

Please give  a hint or confirm, how the planes are defined (first example): plane one contains vectors pC-pS,pB and plane two contains vectors pC-pS,pD. If yes, DihedralAngle[{pS, pC}, {pB   , pD }] should be correct I think.

Edit
The definition of the DihedralAngle is not Well Defined !
For the same two halfplanes HalfPlane[{p1,p2},v1] and HalfPlane[{p1,p2},v2], the DihedralAngle both depend on  the order of {p1,p2} and the order of {v1,v2}, it means that the DihedralAngle in Mathematica is not the well defined function!
Clear["Global`*"];
p1 = {0, 1, 0}; p2 = {0, 0, 0}; v1 = {1, 0, 1}; v2 = {1, 0, 0};
g = Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[5], Blue, Line[{p1, p2}], Red, 
    Arrow[{p1, p1 + v1}], 
    Arrow[{p2, p2 + v2}], {Opacity[.9], Yellow, 
     HalfPlane[{p1, p2}, v1], Green, HalfPlane[{p1, p2}, v2]}}, 
   Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {2.2, -2.2, 1.1}]

{DihedralAngle[{p1, p2}, {v1, v2}], DihedralAngle[{p2, p1}, {v1, v2}],
  DihedralAngle[{p1, p2}, {v2, v1}], 
 DihedralAngle[{p2, p1}, {v2, v1}]}



{(7 π)/4, π/4, π/4, (7 π)/4}

Original
pB = {1, 0, 0};
pC = {1, 1, 0};
pS = {0, 0, 1};
pD = {0, 1, 0};
DihedralAngle[{pS, pC}, {pB - pS, pD - pC}]
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.8], InfinitePlane[{pS, pC, pB}], 
   InfinitePlane[{pS, pC, pD}]}, AbsoluteThickness[5], Blue, 
  Line[{pS, pC}], Red, Arrow[{pS, pB}], Arrow[{pC, pD}], Cyan, 
  Text["pB", pB], Text["pD", pD]}, PlotRange -> 1, 
 ViewPoint -> {2.2, -2.4, -1}, ViewVertical -> {0.8, -0.3, 0.45}]


(2 π)/3

{pS,pC} should be the line of the intersection of the two infiniteplane( the blue line in the picture), and  pB is in one plane, pD is in another plane.


The result of the second example in the original question should be (since the intersection of the two infiniteplane is infinite line through pB and pD,the blue line in the picture)

Clear["Global`*"];
a = 1;
h = Sqrt[2]/2;
pB = {a, 0, 0};
pC = {a, a, 0};
pS = {0, 0, h};
pD = {0, a, 0};
DihedralAngle[{pB, pD}, {pC - pB, pS - pD}]
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.8], InfinitePlane[{pB, pD, pC}], 
   InfinitePlane[{pB, pD, pS}]}, AbsoluteThickness[5], Blue, 
  Line[{pB, pD}], Red, Arrow[{pB, pC}], Arrow[{pD, pS}], Blue, 
  Text["pC", pC], Text["pS", pS]}, PlotRange -> 1, 
 ViewPoint -> {2.7, -1.59, 1.19}, ViewVertical -> {0.35, 0, 0.93}]


(5 π)/4


According to the comment, it must be a bug of DihedralAngle. In the second example, DihedralAngle[{pB, pD}, {pC - pB, pS - pD}] should get (3 π)/4.

DihedralAngle[{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}}, {{u1, u2, u3}, {v1, v2, 
    v3}}] /. Flatten[
  Thread /@ {{x1, y1, z1} -> pB, {x2, y2, z2} -> pD, {u1, u2, u3} -> 
     pC - pB, Thread[{v1, v2, v3} -> pS - pD]}]


(3 π)/4



I think, DihedralAngle of two half planes take value from 0 degree to 180 degree.

@JohnPaulPeter It must be a bug of DihedralAngle, see the example {DihedralAngle[{{a, b, c}, {p, q, r}}, {{u, v, w}, {x, y, z}}] /. {a ->      0, b -> 1, c -> 0, p -> 0, q -> 0, r -> 1, u -> 1, v -> 0,     w -> 1, x -> 1, y -> 0, z -> 0},   DihedralAngle[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}]} The two result should be equal.

@cvgmt See "Possible Issues: DihedralAngle gives generic values for symbolic parameters". By generic they probably mean either the output is alpha or 2*Pi - alpha.

@JohnPaulPeter No, angle of two half planes can take values from 0 to 360 degrees.

@azerbajdzan  But for ArcCos, "For real z between -1 and 1, the results are always in the range 0 to Pi", The result of  DihedralAngle should in the range 0 to Pi.

@cvgmt I am not sure want you are referring to with "For real z between -1 and 1, the results are always in the range 0 to Pi". In general angle between two half-planes are in range from 0 to 2 Pi same as is angle between half-lines given by PlanarAngle in 2D.

@azerbajdzan The result of DihedralAngle should in the range 0 to Pi.

The result of  VectorAngle[{1, 0}, {-1, -1}] is right. DihedralAngle should be the same as VectorAngle.

@cvgmt "DihedralAngle should be the same as VectorAngle" No, it may be your wish but DihedralAngle works more as PlanarAngle than as VectorAngle as I already pointed out in previous comment. See also my answer.

@minhthien_2016 No, see my answer.

I think it's well defined, but the documentation might be a little vague. This line in the documentation, DihedralAngle[{p1,p2},{v,w}] is the length of the arc of the unit circle Circle[p1] on the plane with normal p2-p1 and delimited by the half‐planes HalfPlane[{p1,p2},v] and HalfPlane[{p1,p2},w]., I take to mean: use the right hand rule with p2-p1 from v to w. This implies the answer can change if you permute the arguments.

@GregHurst   It is well defined for  the orientation line p1->p2 and the order of vectors v1->v2, but not well defined for the two halfplanes. So it is not the normal Dihedral Angle, it is the orientation rotation angle of two halfplanes.

Update 2:
For OP's original problem, if only angles in range (0, Pi) are required simply use Pi - Abs[# - Pi] & on output of DihedralAngle:
Pi - Abs[# - Pi] & /@ {4/3 Pi, 5/4 Pi}
Pi - Abs[# - Pi] & /@ {(2 Pi)/3, (3 Pi)/4}


{(2 Pi)/3, (3 Pi)/4}

{(2 Pi)/3, (3 Pi)/4}

We see that angles that are greater than Pi are modified to lie in range (0, Pi) while angles already in range (0, Pi) are unaffected.
Update 1:
Really I do not get what is not understandable about the fact that DihedralAngle computes angles in range (0, 2Pi). If someone wants them in the range (0, Pi) then simply subtract the value of angle that is greater than Pi from 2Pi.
The animation below shows that DihedralAngle works correctly.
SeedRandom[11];
line = Rationalize[RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {2, 3}], 1/10];
v = Rationalize[RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 3], 1/10];

Manipulate[
 Labeled[Graphics3D[{Point[line], Opacity[0.2], Glow@Yellow, 
    HalfPlane[line, v], Glow@Orange, 
    HalfPlane[line, RotationMatrix[fi, -Subtract @@ line] . v], 
    Glow@Orange, Thick, Red, Line[line]}, Boxed -> False, 
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", Black}}, PlotRange -> 20, 
   SphericalRegion -> True], 
  Grid[{{"rotation angle \"fi\" in manipulate: ", 
     fi}, {"angle computed by DihedralAngle: ", 
     DihedralAngle[
      line, {v, RotationMatrix[fi, -Subtract @@ line] . v}]}}, 
   Alignment -> {Center, Center}, ItemSize -> {{20, 5}, {3, 3}}, 
   Frame -> All], Top], {fi, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/100}]



Original answer:
DihedralAngle works correctly and it is an equivalent of PlanarAngle that measure angle between two half-lines in 2D in range (0, 2Pi).
Similarly DihedralAngle measures angle between two half-planes in range (0, 2Pi).
Depends on the orientation of the three vectors red, blue, green in the images.
We can use "right-hand rule" to distinguish which angle will be measured. Right hand thumb points toward direction of red vector and bent fingers show direction of an angle from the first vector (blue) to the second vector (green).
We see that the first and second images depict the same situation just order of blue and green vectors is swapped, hence if the first angle is alpha the second is 2Pi - alpha.
See also documentation of DihedralAngle in section "Possible Issues" we can read  "DihedralAngle gives generic values for symbolic parameters".
line = {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
v = {{1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}};

Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], Glow@Yellow, HalfPlane[line, v[[1]]], 
  Glow@Orange, HalfPlane[line, v[[2]]], Opacity[1], Glow[Red], 
  Arrow@Tube[line], Glow[Blue], 
  Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0} + line[[1]], v[[1]] + line[[1]]}], 
  Glow[Green], 
  Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0} + line[[1]], v[[2]] + line[[1]]}], 
  Glow[Black], 
  Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0} + line[[2]], v[[1]] + line[[2]]}], 
  Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0} + line[[2]], v[[2]] + line[[2]]}]}, 
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", Black}}]
DihedralAngle[line, v]

v = Reverse@v;

Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], Glow@Yellow, HalfPlane[line, v[[1]]], 
  Glow@Orange, HalfPlane[line, v[[2]]], Opacity[1], Glow[Red], 
  Arrow@Tube[line], Glow[Blue], 
  Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0} + line[[1]], v[[1]] + line[[1]]}], 
  Glow[Green], 
  Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0} + line[[1]], v[[2]] + line[[1]]}], 
  Glow[Black], 
  Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0} + line[[2]], v[[1]] + line[[2]]}], 
  Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, 0} + line[[2]], v[[2]] + line[[2]]}]}, 
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", Black}}]
DihedralAngle[line, v]





When we reverse v, (DihedralAngle[{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}}, {{u1, u2, u3}, {v1, v2,        v3}}] /. Flatten[     Thread /@ {{x1, y1, z1} -> line[[1]], {x2, y2, z2} ->         line[[2]], {u1, u2, u3} -> v[[1]],        Thread[{v1, v2, v3} -> v[[2]]]}]) == (DihedralAngle[{{x1, y1,        z1}, {x2, y2, z2}}, {{u1, u2, u3}, {v1, v2, v3}}] /.     Flatten[Thread /@ {{x1, y1, z1} -> line[[1]], {x2, y2, z2} ->         line[[2]], {u1, u2, u3} -> v[[2]],        Thread[{v1, v2, v3} -> v[[1]]]}]) is True

@cvgmt I guess I have already wrote it to you three times: See also documentation of DihedralAngle in section "Possible Issues" we can read "DihedralAngle gives generic values for symbolic parameters". This is the situation when you used symbolic parameters so you got "generic values" which may be different compared when explicit values are used.

This means that  DihedralAngle is not well defined. Unacceptable such situation.

@cvgmt It is well defined. There does not always exist a formula that would produce correct result for all possible inputs for symbolic parameters. Or if it exists it would probably contain lots of If-s. But you can derive your own formula for symbolic parameters if you think you can do better than formula implemented currently in Mathematica.

I believe that the definition of DihedralAngle in Mathematica is not the normal definition since it is depend on both the orientation of the intersection line and the orientation of the two planes  . {DihedralAngle[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}],   DihedralAngle[   Reverse@{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}],   DihedralAngle[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},    Reverse@{{1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}],   DihedralAngle[Reverse@{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},    Reverse@{{1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}]} It is difference to the mathematics book.

@azerbajdzan, In my country, the result of DihedralAngle must in the range 0 to Pi.

@cvgmt The definition in Mathematica is more general and more useful than that of your books.

@azerbajdzan  A function is not Well Defined is not useful!

See the animation  agian by setting Reverse@line.

@cvgm No problem. Animation and DihedralAngle still work correctly no matter what values are set for 'line' or 'v'.
